# Configure webmatrix3 mysql connection UI on port different from 3306

Tags: mysql, connection-string, webmatrix

I tried to connect to an existing mySQL connection with webmatrix, but I cannot specify a port different from 3306.
I tried to put as server:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:myport
```

or

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx myport
```

but it cannot connect.
I also tried to edit web.config file, writing a regular mysql connection specifying port=myport, but it seems that Webmatrix ignore that.

Comment: I've seen some Microsoft stuff use a comma as a port delimiter, ie `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,myport`. Worth a try?

Comment: Just tried, but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't try it yet on the "port" parameter, but it should work if you connect the database and set the connection string like this:

```
@{
    var cs = "Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;";
    var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(cs, "MySql.Data.MySqlClient");
}
```

I used this workaround to add extra params that webmatrix just ignored when I put them into the web.config. You can alter the connectionString after getting it from the configuration file like this:

```
@{
    var cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["connectionString_name"];
    var cs_Altered = cs.ConnectionString + ";Command Timeout=120";
    var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(cs_Altered, cs.ProviderName);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand In which file do I have to write this.

Comment: @kiks73 there where you set your `var db = Database.Open("connectionString_name");`, usualy in your `default.cshtml` source _(This will not work for the webmatrix databases UI, but for that local case I suggest you to do something like a port forward/redirect on your router)_.

Comment: I have no problems to connect to my db in php files, the issue is just in webmatrix databases ui. I'll try to manage it from the router, as you suggest.

Comment: Okay, i didn't catch that from your first post. So in your case, yes, port translation is the way to go until [webmatrix does support it](http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/forums/128313-webmatrix-suggestions/suggestions/2560856-add-support-for-alternate-ports-on-mysql-databases)